# submit form with <a></a> tag via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I use this code to submit my form with a tag but its not working

### html file

```
<form id="my_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="number" name="conf" ><a onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();" href="{% url 'signup' 0 %}">ارسال کد</a>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">ثبت نام</button>
</form>
```

### console log

```
 "GET /signup/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1531
```

The output I expect

```
"POST /signup/0 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: The request is sent and the response is `200 OK` - So what's the problem?

Comment: i wanna submit form so form is post method but it well send it as get look console log

Comment: There are several issues in your code that might fix your problem. a) If you want several buttons that should submit the form but do different actions, you should place several submit buttons and use the `name` attribute to distinguish the actions. `<input type="submit" name="send_code">Send Code</input>`. b) The form tag is lagging an `action` attribute. c) [type=number is not the right input type for codes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate)

Comment: @Andy `action` is not required. If it is not explicitly defined it's default action/value is the current document.

Comment: in your a tag you have `href="{% url 'signup' 0 %}"` this will redirect instead of POST the form, that why you got GET method instead of POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is the following line

```html
<a onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();" href="{% url 'signup' 0 %}">Send Code</a>
```

Because it’s a link, the browser will handle it’s click. You’d need to add `return false;` to your click handler to stop the browser following the link, or [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Maybe it’s worth mentioning that the `href` attribute will not do anything then. Except for making the `<a>` a real link, focusable and can be activated.

```html
<a onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); return false;" href="{% url 'signup' 0 %}">Send Code</a>
```

### Taking different actions from the same form

But in any case, a button would be more appropriate, since you are submitting the form as well.

Your `href` attribute and link text make it seem like you want to still submit the form, but take a different action when clicking “Send Code”. For this purpose HTML suggests using several submit buttons with different names, that then can be differentiated on the server.

Or you can add [the `formaction` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction) to the button to send the form to a different URL.

```html
<form id="my_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <label for="conf">Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="conf" name="conf" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d+">
    <button type="submit" name="send_code">Send Code</button>
OR
    <button type="submit" formaction="{% url 'signup' 0 %}">Send Code</button>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Note also that I added a label to the code field, since every input needs a label. And I changed the input type for the code, as [`type="number"` is not the right input type for codes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate). The following will make sure on-screen keyboards will be optimised to enter numbers and provide some hints to improve usability.

```
<label for="conf">Code</label>
<input type="text" id="conf" name="conf" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d+" size="6" placeholder="123456">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function on a click attribute on tag A

Comment: You should try to explain how this solves the user’s issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is becouse first by clicking a tag you do default action witch is href in a tag. The onclick won't fire after default action if you don't add `preventDefault()`

and if you want to send form to your signup url you need to add it in form tag :

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="{% url 'signup' 0 %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="number" name="conf" >

<br><br>
<button type="submit">ثبت نام</button>
```

Comment: _"you need to add it in form tag"_ - Not if its the same document...